# Spring: returning immediately response via Rest API and letting service layer to deal with request

Tags: java, spring-boot, concurrency, java.util.concurrent

In my application I have the following scenario: when client via Restful API sends request, it is saved into database and it of the id of persisted object is returned to the client. Later, using scheduler (i.e. `@Scheduler`), the request made before is retrieved from the database and it is processed. This way the client immediately gets its response via Restful API (more precisely: the identifier of the result but not the result itself) and the result itself is calculated later as it is time-consuming. I wonder whether there are better options.

Namely,I was thinking of writing a Rest API where the web layer hands over the domain object to the service player. The service layer saves this domain object to the database, then returns the id of the domain object to the web layer, and finally  executes the time consuming-task.

After reading about `CompletableFuture` I decided to give it a try. However, my code still waits for the time-consuming task to be finished and only then returns id to the web layer. Please see an (much simplified) example:

```
public int completableFuture(Dto dto) {

       Domain domain = saveToDB(dto);

       CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(this::calculateTimeConsumingTask) // accepts domain object
                .thenAcceptAsync(this::saveResult);
       return domain.getId();
    }
```

Comment: That code won't compile, with a `return` before another statement.

Comment: Is there a chance for you to implement JMS for the async task. Useful links: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22088873/how-to-understand-the-synchronous-and-asynchronouns-messaging-in-jms .    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39709360/why-and-when-should-we-use-asynchronous-messaging-like-jms-or-amqp

Comment: @daniu You are right. Fixing this.

Comment: This _general_ model is common for long-running jobs: Assign an ID that the client can use to check back (or you can make callbacks via webhook). Take a look at the _Claim Check_ design pattern. Typically in implementation you would set up a producer-consumer type arrangement where some other executor is responsible for checking the queue and doing processing.

Comment: use the @Async annotation for these kind of operations and not completable futures

Comment: I agree with @ThomasAndolf